# Space between section and starting point of paragraph

Tags: sectioning

All the sections are correct, however the last section has given me the extra space seen in the attached photo. The question, is I want to remove the space between the title of the section and the start of the paragraph, how can I do that?

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt, titlepage,headings=optiontohead]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}%
%\usepackage[T1,plmath]{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % sort and compress citations

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\rhead{Chpter One}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % brak podziaÂ?u wyraz??w
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=3.6cm, bmargin=3.6cm, lmargin=3.2cm, rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\graphicspath{ {Graphics/Figures/} }

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}

%%%%%% % fix long section titles in toc 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% the following three lines only if the class is report or book
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #1 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #2 is the mandatory argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{}
%%%
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #7 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #8 is the mandatory argument
\makeatother 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}




    \title{\textbf{Chapter One: Asors}}
    \author{TOHFARD}

    
    
    
    \maketitle
%   \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
%   \newpage
    \listoffigures
%   \newpage
    
    %[M for M: Rew]

    %\textbf{Abdjeh}
    %\tableofcontents
    \chapter[AM forew]{ture Review}

    \newpage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \section[AM tions]{Additive acturing}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    zdfg

\newpage
    \section[Conclusion]{Summary}
    Addressed in this chapter is the definition and motivations of employing a process for fabrication different materials, dfgdt methods of 3D printing are provided with the focus on the FDM method. Also, composite material is dfhsfgsnually results in removing the erroneous output values.
    
    
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \section[Acknowledgements]{Acknowledgements}
    sfand for their continuous support of this study. The reseasdfs under, M-ERA.NET 2 Csgdfgs2019".

    
    
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to have a question, there is currently no question here, just a statement that you want to change some space but not very clear which space you want to change or what you want to change it to

Comment: Done .........................

Comment: You mention an "attached photo." Please make it visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have resolved after adding another `\newpage` after the summary section.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt, titlepage,headings=optiontohead]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}%
%\usepackage[T1,plmath]{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % sort and compress citations

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\rhead{Chpter One}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % brak podziaÂ?u wyraz??w
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=3.6cm, bmargin=3.6cm, lmargin=3.2cm, rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\graphicspath{ {Graphics/Figures/} }

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}

%%%%%% % fix long section titles in toc 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% the following three lines only if the class is report or book
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #1 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #2 is the mandatory argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{}
%%%
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #7 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #8 is the mandatory argument
\makeatother 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \title{\textbf{Chapter One: Asors}}
    \author{TOHFARD}

    \maketitle
%   \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
%   \newpage
    \listoffigures
%   \newpage
    
    %[M for M: Rew]

    %\textbf{Abdjeh}
    %\tableofcontents
    \chapter[AM forew]{ture Review}

    \newpage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \section[AM tions]{Additive acturing}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    zdfg

\newpage
    \section[Conclusion]{Summary}
    Addressed in this chapter is the definition and motivations of employing a process for fabrication different materials, dfgdt methods of 3D printing are provided with the focus on the FDM method. Also, composite material is dfhsfgsnually results in removing the erroneous output values.
    \newpage %<--------------- ADDED
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \section[Acknowledgements]{Acknowledgements}
    sfand for their continuous support of this study. The reseasdfs under, M-ERA.NET 2 Csgdfgs2019".
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

As an aside, you were loading `hyperref` twice, once on its own with `hidelinks` and another with `lineno` package, load it (and any package) once. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have reduced the space following the last `\section` in your MWE using basic LaTeX coding. Look for `\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection`

```
% secspaceprob.tex  SE 641420
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt, titlepage,headings=optiontohead]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}%
%\usepackage[T1,plmath]{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % sort and compress citations

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\rhead{Chpter One}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % brak podziaÂ?u wyraz??w
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=3.6cm, bmargin=3.6cm, lmargin=3.2cm, rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage%[nottoc]
    {tocbibind}

%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\graphicspath{ {Graphics/Figures/} }

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}

%%%%%% % fix long section titles in toc 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% the following three lines only if the class is report or book
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #1 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{} % #2 is the mandatory argument
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{#1}{#2}{}{}
%%%
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #7 is the optional argument
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi#8}{}{} % #8 is the mandatory argument
\makeatother 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \title{\textbf{Chapter One: Asors}}
    \author{TOHFARD}
    
    \maketitle
%   \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
%   \newpage
    \listoffigures
%   \newpage
    
    %[M for M: Rew]

    %\textbf{Abdjeh}
    %\tableofcontents
    \chapter[AM forew]{ture Review}

    \newpage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \section[AM tions]{Additive acturing}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    zdfg

\newpage
    \section[Conclusion]{Summary}
    Addressed in this chapter is the definition and motivations of employing a process for fabrication different materials, dfgdt methods of 3D printing are provided with the focus on the FDM method. Also, composite material is dfhsfgsnually results in removing the erroneous output values.
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% change section formatting
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
      {section}{1}{0pt}% % name, level, indent (as normal)
      {3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}% skip before title (as normal)
      {0.3ex plus .2ex}% skip after title (usually 2.3 ex plus .2ex)  
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}} % the font as normal
    \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
    
    \pagebreak
    
    \section[Acknowledgements]{Acknowledgements}
    sfand for their continuous support of this study. The reseasdfs under, M-ERA.NET 2 Csgdfgs2019".

       
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

If you had used the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) it would have been simply

\setaftersecskip{0.5ex plus 0.2ex}

Comment: Thanks but it did not work:(. Run yourself you would see it there is a large gap

Comment: @AhmadTurani Your question was edited after I posted my answer. You added a picture that showed your problem but all I had to do in was your descriptive text. As I said I reduced the space after the last section but following the edit that was not the space you wanted reduced.